# how to drop multiple tables that start with the same string in ADX using Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have 100+ tables in Azure Data Explorer and they all start with the same string.
I want to drop them all but it seems like .drop tables string* doesn't work..

How can I drop multiple tables at once?

any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the following to generate the text of a `.drop tables` command, then invoke that text as the 2nd step.

```
.show tables
| where TableName startswith "MyPrefix"
| summarize cmd = strcat(
    ".drop tables (",
    strcat_array(make_list(strcat("['", TableName, "']")), ","),
    ")"
)
```